# php get part of a string before div and after comman

Tags: php, string

Please can somebody help me? I only need to get the part of a word in a string using PHP. In the following example I need to get the word Kimberley from the following string:

```
13 Angel Street, El Toro Park, Kimberley <div Id='rentals' Class='rentals'>Agencies</div> <div Id='rentalsix' Class='rentals'>5</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$searchaddress = 13 Angel Street, El Toro Park, Kimberley <div Id='rentals' 
Class='rentals'>Agencies</div> <div Id='rentalsix' Class='rentals'>5</div>;

preg_match('|<[^>]*rentals[^>]*>(.*?)<|', $searchaddress, $m);
$newvalue = $m[1];
echo htmlspecialchars($newvalue));
```

It works but it only gets the word Agenncies out of the string. I need the word Kimbherley.

Comment: Do you need both words? Kimbherley and Agenncies ? and is this case specific.

Comment: did you try with `explode("<div",$searchaddress)` function? Or you need all strings with out `DIV`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. No, I only need the work Kimberley. Please

Comment: You can also try this simple regex to get the word before the `<div` element(s): `(\w+)\s*<div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help.

```
  //this is your string.
    $text = '13 Angel Street, El Toro Park, Kimberley <div Id=\'rentals\' Class=\'rentals\'>Agencies</div> <div Id=\'rentalsix\' Class=\'rentals\'>5</div>';
    //find position of ',' from where you want to explode using strrpos
        $pos=strrpos($text,',',2);
    // explode string from given postion.
        $text=substr($text,$pos);
    //find the text that exist between ',' and  starting bracket of div '<'
        preg_match('#,(.*?)<#', $text, $match);
    // output
        var_dump( $match[1]);
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. It gets the city name even if it contains two or more words.

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp = explode(' <div', $searchaddress );
$exp = explode(' ', $exp[0]);
$exp = $exp[count($exp)-1];
```

as variant.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore HTML tags use `strip_tags` PHP function.
for detail see this link [STRIPTAGS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

If you want first string before the first div then use `explode` function.

```
$searchaddress = 13 Angel Street, El Toro Park, Kimberley <div Id='rentals' 
Class='rentals'>Agencies</div> <div Id='rentalsix' Class='rentals'>5</div>;

strip_tags($searchaddress);
```

To get only the first part of a string.

```
$str   =   explode("<div",$searchaddress);
echo $str[0];
```